# ACF indicates non-stationarity but but time series plot looks stationary

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, autocorrelation, stationarity

I am trying to choose the correct ARIMA model.
To get a stationary series on which to plot the ACF and PACF on I've done the following transformations on my original series:

1. natural log
2. 1st non-seasonal differences
3. 1st seasonal differences of the non-seasonal differences

Judging from my time series plot(included below) the final series seems stationary but unfortunately I can't interpret the ACF plot. It looks to me like it would need further or different transformations.

This is my [data set](https://docs.google.com/a/georgetown.edu/spreadsheets/d/17WBLhMSZzwM7DObinfoTwN9Fv36tOC1JR3vZJIE4Uq8/edit?usp=sharing) with the transformations I've done.

I included my plots below. I am using minitab 18 to generate these.

### Time Series Plot of Original Series

[image: Time Series Og]

### Time Series Plot of Transformed Series

[image: Time Series Transformed]

### ACF of Transformed Series (Lags: 48)

[image: ACF]

### PACF of Transformed Series (Lags: 48)

[image: PACF]

### ACF of 1st Non-seasonal Diff:

[image: ACF 1st Diff]

### PACF of 1st Non-seasonal Diff:

[image: PACF 1st Diff]

Comment: What does the original series look like?

Comment: Hi @MichaelChernick! I've just updated my question with a time series plot of the original series. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the series are clearly non-stationary judging by the original series

Comment: @Aksakal, yes I agree which is why I transformed the series with the 3 steps described in my question and the time series plot of my transformed series looks stationary to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would run ACF/PACF on a simple first difference of log of series and see what comes. You have annual seasonality. You have less than 200 observations, I wouldn't worry about lags beyond 12, there's not too many observations to calculate them robustly

Comment: @Aksakal, so you are saying that even though I have annual seasonality (lag 12) I shouldn't try to remove seasonality from my series because it isn't long enough to accurately determine seasonal effects?

Comment: No, you can try ARIMA(12,1,0). I don't jump into advanced lag structure before looking at residuals of simple log diff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68850/discussion-between-herteladrian-and-aksakal).

Comment: How can you say that the original series looks stationary.  There is clearly an increasing trend.

Comment: Watch out for overdifferencing. The series does not appear to have a unit root, making differencing irrelevant and detrimental. Rather, there seems to be a deterministic trend in your series, and increasing variance. I would therefore take a logarithmic transformation of the series to linearize the trend and equalize the variance. However, I would not difference afterwards, unlike Aksakal, due to the reason explained above. @MichaelChernick, if there is a trend in levels and in variance, how can the series be stationary? Perhaps you meant trend-stationarity after a logarithmic transformation?

Comment: @MichaelChernick, yes the original series is clearly non stationary but my transformed series looks stationary to me.

Comment: I was only criticizing the statement in your post that the final series looks stationary which presumably is the bottom figure. There is no plot here of the transformed series.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, thank you for your criticism but there is a plot for the transformed series. Do you see the plot with the title "Time Series Plot of Transformed Series"?

Comment: I didn't realize that your transformed series was the first difference series. But for stationarity the variance must stay constant also.  This is not clear from the plot.  Note also Richard Hardy's comment.

Answer (score 1):

[image] is a useful model for the most recent 78 values. There is a significant change in parameters over time (approx period 111) which is clearly visual from the time series plot. This conclusion was based on the CHOW test for constant parameters. Seasonal differencing (order 12) is needed without any power transform. Note the need for a quarterly auto-regressive effect often overlooked in the rush to just using 12 period effects suggesting tw0 seasonal effects. Finally a single anomaly is identified at the  penultimate point in time (period 187)